# can't install i386 packages on Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: apt, server, package-management, updates, cloud

I am using the version Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-1027-oracle aarch64) trying to add i386.

I was wanting to install a program called byond, and this program runs only with a 32-bit package.
I followed this step by step from them: [Updated guide to running BYOND (DreamDaemon) on Debian/Ubuntu based distros](http://www.byond.com/forum/post/2780956)

I Have tried to install it via the command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

And:

```
sudo apt update
```

And I get the error

```
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Err:6 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:7 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:10 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:11 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:17 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:18 http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then this

```
sudo apt install libstdc++6:i386
```

And in the end

```
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libstdc++6:i386
```

How can I resolve this error? Is it something related to the (/etc/apt/sources.list) file ? Or about the processor architecture (Arm-based processor) ?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: I was wanting to install a program called byond, and this program requires 32-bit packages. 
I was following this [step](http://www.byond.com/forum/post/2780956).

Comment: Main problem is wrong architecture. Look into using a Virtual Machine (an x86 emulator) like QEMU for your project. Ubuntu (amd64 architecture) in a VM will compile without any of those errors...and the final compiled binary will run properly (it probably won't run natively on your aarch64). If your system is too low-power to run a proper VM, then you are out of luck with the hardware you have.

Comment: understood then, thanks for the answer @user535733